# Rails_admin, cancancan for authorization, devise for authentication. Login Redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, rails-admin

when I attempt to navigate to /admin. Cancancan raises an execption if there is no user logged in and if there is a non admin user logged in. I would like to be redirected to a login screen - if the log in is successful, proceed to the rails_admin dashboard.

See below, my present code/config, please let me know if you need more info:

`/app/models/ability.rb`

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user && user.admin?
      can :access, :rails_admin       # only allow admin users to access Rails Admin
      can :dashboard
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all                   # allow everyone to read everything
    end

  end
end
```

`/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  ### Popular gems integration

  # == Devise ==
  # config.authenticate_with do
  #   warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  # end
  # config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  # == Cancan ==
  config.authorize_with :cancan

  ## == Pundit ==
  # config.authorize_with :pundit

  ## == PaperTrail ==
  # config.audit_with :paper_trail, 'User', 'PaperTrail::Version' # PaperTrail >= 3.0.0

  ### More at https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Base-configuration

  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app

    ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
    # history_index
    # history_show
  end

  config.model 'User' do
    create do
      field :name
      field :email
      field :password
      field :password_confirmation
      field :role
    end

    edit do
      field :name
      field :email
      field :password
      field :password_confirmation
      field :role
    end
  end


end
```

`/config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  # authenticate :admin do
  #   mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: :rails_admin
  # end

  root to: 'visitors#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  devise_scope :user do
    get "signup", to: "devise/registrations#new"
    get "login", to: "devise/sessions#new"
    get "logout", to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: 'logout'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to rescue from a CanCan::AccessDenied Exception.

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to login_path, :alert => exception.message
end
```

Replace `login_path` with the actual path name of your login. You an find it by doing a `rake routes` and finding the entry that's pointing to `devise/sessions#new`

You can also make the logic more robust and only redirect if they are trying to visit a page in the admin area.

Comment: its **not** catching in `rails-5-api` for `rails_admin` at `/admin`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation, and I was able to redirect no admin to root path. I'm using `Rails 5` and `Ruby 2.3` Here is my settings:

**admin rails**

```
# config/initialize/rails_admin.rb
  config.authorize_with do
    unless current_user.try(:admin?)
       flash[:error] = "You are not authorize to access this page!"
      redirect_to main_app.root_path
    end
  end
```

**CanCanCan**

```
# models/ability.rb
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :manage, :all if user.role == "user"
  end
```

When a user try to access `/admin` it gets redirect to root path with a flash error.